# Spring MVC handle unmapped request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am starting a project with all the html pages ready. So, now I have to create all the controller to handle requests and display a view. Before create all the controller, could I have a "generic" controller which get the view which correspond with the route.

For example, I have spring mvc+ thymeleaf. I have all my .html in WebContent/WEB-INF/templates with the resolver:

```
private ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
    resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    return resolver;
}
```

The first and only controller I have created is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(Model model) {
    return "authentication/login.html";
}
```

So, can I have a 'generic' controller which handle the rest of request so that if you write 'http://localhost:8080/authentication/register.html', the generic controller will get the view in 'authentication/register.html'?

Comment: have you tried smth like [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/19404-how-to-map-urls-to-jsps-without-the-custom-controller)

Comment: @AntJavaDev I am extending `UrlFilenameViewController` and overriding `postProcessViewName` without any success. Spring ignores the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the templates are static, you can serve those as resources. Read [spring documentation on that topic](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-static-resources).

Basically it would look like

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/WEB-INF/templates/"/>
```

or

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/templates/");
    }

}
```

depending on type of spring configuration in the project.

Comment: Any idea if I need html as dynamic? I am using Thymeleaf. Althoug is fine this solution as I will be creating the controllers as I need them for dynamic content.